# Why is read.delim or read.csv function in r not separating file into columns?

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I am trying to read some text files which are tab delimited in R using the following codes. This code works for some files but not for others even if they are the output files from same program. Can anyone help me on whats going on. I even tried to change the tab delimited files to csv file but the problem is same.

```
## file.txt
77134|102241
77134|102243
77134|18985
77134|22487
77134|55044
77134|55045     K01684
77134|55048     K07824
77134|55049     K23978
77134|55059     K06978
77134|55064

file1<- read.delim("file.txt", header = FALSE, sep="\t")
```

However this code is reading two columns in file as a single column like below:

```
head (file1)

77134|102241
77134|102243
77134|18985
77134|22487
77134|55044
77134|55045
K01684
77134|55048
K07824
77134|55049
K23978
77134|55059
K06978
```

When I use read.lines function it gives the following result (in here I tried the csv delimited file therefore there is comma not tab)

```
[1] "77134|102241"        "77134|102243"        "77134|18985"         "77134|22487"        
   [5] "77134|55044"         "77134|55045,K01684"  "77134|55048,K07824"  "77134|55049,K23978" 
   [9] "77134|55059,K06978"  "77134|55064"         "77134|55065"         "77134|55084"        
  [13] "77134|55089"         "77134|55090,K00077"  "77134|55092"         "77134|64914"
```

Does anyone have any clue whats going on? I changed the tsv file to csv and tried using read.csv function, but the problem is not solved. Please help.

Comment: Can you use `read.table`? And see whether the problem exists

Comment: Yes the problem is same

Comment: Your data might be complicated than it looks. It might have embedded [\r\n] in it. Especially if using different platforms. Consider including the results of `readLines(yourfile` in your question

Comment: @onyambu I just edited the question as you said.

Comment: Seems to me that the comma somewhere. ie check the 6th element. Where did the comma come from?

Comment: @onyambu all of these "tab" delimited text files were generated in through KEGG analysis. I tried to change these "tabs" to "comma" in shell script. I just opened all of these csv files in excel and rerun the same code and now it is working. I don't know what happened but I am glad it worked. Thank you so much for you help !!